# Include native library in NuGet package consumed by Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

I have a two-part project. Part one is a set of C# bindings that wrap a native .dll or .so library. This produces a NugGet package, which is then consumed by the other project.

The other is a Xamarin Forms project that consumes those C# bindings. The UWP portion of my Xamarin project has no issue finding the native library inside the NuGet package. The Android project, however, cannot find it. Indeed, opening the APK reveals that the native .so file never makes it in.

I'm using [NuGet's mechanism for including arch-specific libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#architecture-specific-folders), by including each platform-specific .dll-or-.so in a `/runtimes/platform-arch/native/` folder. My folder structure looks like this for the bindings project:

[image: Folder structure of bindings project]

...and I can confirm that the folder structure is properly preserved in the resulting `.nupkg` file, with a `runtimes` folder at the root of the package, and a series of subfolders underneath it.

I generate the NuGet package by using the new built in .csproj mechanisms, without any .targets files. My csproj for the NuGet project looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <Version>1.0.5.1</Version>
    <Company />
    <Product />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="runtimes\**" PackagePath="runtimes">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OneOf" Version="2.1.150" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The second part of my project is a Xamarin Forms project, and I import the NuGet package to the .NET Standard cross-platform portion of the project.

When I build the UWP project, my platform-specific `.dll` is correctly copied to the root of my `.appx` file, and I can successfully P/Invoke it. (I have noticed that this only works if I build in an x64 configuration, and I am compiling on an x64 machine.) However, when building the Android project, no such thing happens with the `.so` Android library.

The entire dependency chain looks something like this:

```
-------------NuGet Package----------
|   - native_lib.so                |
|   - (other runtime dlls, etc)    |
------------------------------------
                 ^
                 |                 
-----Xamarin.Forms Core Project-----
| - Imports NuGet                  |
------------------------------------
                  ^
                  |
-------Xamarin Android Project------
| - Imports Xamarin Forms Core Proj|
| - Produces APK                   |
------------------------------------
```

It does not seem to be a naming issue--attempting to rename `native_lib.so` in the bindings project to `libnative_lib.so` has no effect.

Am I missing a step, or does NuGet simply not understand that a Xamarin.Android project needs native libraries copied into the APK?

Source code for the NuGet project: https://github.com/pingzing/scannitsharp
Source code for the Xamarin Forms project that consumes the NuGet: https://github.com/pingzing/scannit
NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ScannitSharp/1.0.5.1

Comment: Is the android project using packages.config or PackageReference? How sure are you about the runtime identifier (RID)?

Comment: It's using PackageReference (though it doesn't have a direct dependency on the bindings library--only the cross-platform Xamarin Forms library, which depends upon the NuGet package). As for the RID, I'm pretty sure: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json
I suppose I could try just plain 'android'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you need to share more info in your Q, such as your code and packaging files.

> does NuGet simply not understand that a Xamarin.Android project needs native libraries copied into the APK?

Yes it does. You need to package your NuGet in a way that MSBuild includes this file in the final APK.

For Android, this is done with `AndroidNativeLibrary`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process#item-attribute-name

And a working example here https://github.com/mfkl/libvlc-nuget/blob/master/build/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Android.targets

> I have noticed that this only works if I build in an x64 configuration, and I am compiling on an x64 machine.

You likely need to modify your targets file to handle the 3 possibles cases `AnyCPU`, `x86` and `x64`. Your target should run before the actual build, with `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`.

You can use something like

```
<Content Include="@(WindowsX64IncludeFilesFullPath)">
        <Link>$(WindowsX64TargetDir)\$([MSBuild]::MakeRelative($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\build\x64\, %(FullPath)))</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Check this out: https://github.com/mfkl/libvlc-nuget/blob/master/build/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.targets

Comment: Re: more info in the question - Fair. I can add more information about the NuGet's packaging process.

"Yes it does. You need to package your NuGet in a way that MSBuild includes this file in the final APK. For Android, this is done with AndroidNativeLibrary" -- This doesn't work for me though--the .so file is included in the NuGet package, which is just a  .NET Standard library. By the time I get to the Xamarin Android project, I no longer have visibility on it.

Comment: "By the time I get to the Xamarin Android project, I no longer have visibility on it." I don't know what that means. Just share your code please

Comment: Question updated with more information. And I mean that the Xamarin Android project has no idea that a native lib is involved at all. It references the Xamarin Forms Netstandard project, which references a NuGet package which contains a .so file. I don't use a custom `.targets` file for any part of this process.

Comment: "I don't use a custom .targets file for any part of this process"

That's your problem. You need one and use `AndroidNativeLibrary`. `CopyToOutputDirectory` is not going to cut it for android native libs packaging.

Comment: Makes sense. So to confirm that I understand this: my final `.nupkg` must contain a `/build/Scannit.targets` (does the name matter here?) which contains platform specific library-handling, i.e. `<AndroidNativeLibrary>` for Android, and handling the various architectures for Windows.
Then, at (or just before, or just after, etc) build time, the `.targets` file will run its tasks for any project that its NuGet package is included in?

Comment: Marking this as the answer, because it ultimately set me on the correct path. I was missing two steps: 1) Include a ScannitSharp.targets file in the /build folder of the NuGet package, that uses the <AndroidNativeLibrary> declaration, and 2) Include the library in both the Xamarin Netstandard library AND the platform-specific Android project.

Comment: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-items#androidnativelibrary) to go right to the section on `AndroidNativeLibrary`.